# Cannot pass variables to a spark sql query in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python variable (I am using pyspark) of date datatype:
The variable value is 2016-10-31

```
print type(load_dt)

 >> <type 'datetime.date'>
```

I am having difficulty passing this to a sparksql query:

```
    hive_context.sql("select * from  tbl t1 where cast (substring(t1.dt,1,10) as date) ={0}".format(load_dt));

    Error:

    u"cannot resolve '(cast(substring(dt,1,10) as date) = ((2016 - 10) - 31))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(cast(substring(period_dt,1,10) as date) = ((2016 - 10) - 31))'
 (date and int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes:

```
"select * from  tbl t1 where cast (substring(t1.dt,1,10) as date) = '{0}'"
```

otherwise date is converted to `2016-10-31` string and interpreted as arithmetic expression:

```
2016 - 10 - 31
```